# Determine Covariance for multivariate normal distribution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, distribution

I am trying to create a bivariate normal distribution of random numbers in Matlab that is symmetrical.  I know the standard deviation of the gaussian (15 for example) and that it is the same in both directions.  How do I use this standard deviation information to get the covariance in a form that Matlab will accept for the mvnrnd command?  Thanks, I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "symmetrical". Do you mean rotational symmetry, i.e. sphericity?

Answer (score 1):

*If the random variables are independent*, the off-diaginal elements of the covariance matrix are zero. So that matrix will be `diag(std1,std2)`, where `std1` and `std2` are the standard deviations of your two variables. In your example you would use `diag(15,15)`.

If the random variables are *not* independent, you need to specify all four elements of the covariance matrix.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to know the correlation between the two normal variables. Like @Luis said, the diagonal will be 15 each but for the covariance, you need to know the correlation between both.

They are related by this equation:

```
cov(x,y) = correlation(x,y)*std(x)*std(y)
```

But if you do not know the correlation, then you can calculate the sample covariance.

Forumla for sample covariance:

[image]

To calculate in Matlab:

```
cov = (1/n)*(x-mean(x))*(y-mean(y))'
```

With reference to:http://www.cogsci.ucsd.edu/~desa/109/trieschmarksslides.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command cov in Matlab:

```
SIGMA = cov([x y]);
```

HTH